# External display for MacBook Retina 12" (2017) with boot while lid is closed

Tags: display

I have a  [MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, 2017) - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP757?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Which external monitor would allow me to boot the computer without opening the lid?

I am looking for a high quality monitor at 32 inches at least...